# What is the best way to show indicator for in-flight requests using rxjs without side-effects?

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the preferred way to show a loading indicator for an inflight request using RXJS (and Angular2+) without introducing side effects within the pipe() function?

Here are the options I've come up with. Is there a cannoncial recommendation or a better option?

---

Option 1: Use side effects via do();

```
results$ = userEvent$.pipe(do(()=> { this.loading = true; }), switchMap(()=>  service.externalCall()), do(()=> { this.loading = false; }))
```

Pros: Simplest
Cons: Can run into edge cases with multiple subscribers unless using 'share'.

---

Option 2: Add separate subscribes for setting the loading indicator

```
userEvent$.subscribe(()=> {this.loading = true;} )
const results$ = userEvent$.pipe(switchMap(()=>  service.externalCall()))
// Is this always guarenteed to fire after the first statement?
results$.subscribe(() => {this.loading = false;});
```

Pros:
No side effects within the pipe() operator

Cons: 
More observables floating around
Not clear if the order is deterministic.

---

Option 3: Create a new subject

```
const subject = new Subject();
userEvent$.subscribe(()=> { this.loading = true; subject.next(); } )
const result$ = subject.asObservable().pipe(switchMap(() => service.externalCall()));
result$.subscribe(() => { this.loading = false; });
```

Pros:
100% deterministic, no side effects

Cons:
Have to introduce another subject

Comment: What do you mean by side effects? Making an HTTP is itself a side effect

Comment: On a side note, sounds like you can use the `reportProgress` option for this as well

Comment: @Dummy, altering component instance variables within pipe() instead of  the subscribe() block.

Comment: Are you using ngrx? If so, you can dispatch an action to toggle your indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use a side-effect (`do/tap`) because it is simpler.

You could use an approach where you model all messages as events. So the events going down the same pipe could be 'Loading', 'Success', 'Failure', etc. I have seen this approach with ngrx effects specifically. Then you just filter based on what you want. You have to share if you have multiple subscriptions (which you probably will). Here is an example.

```js
console.clear();
const { interval, of, throwError: _throw } = rxjs;
const { switchMap, take, delay, map, startWith, catchError, share } = rxjs.operators;

let callCount = 0;
function fakeApiCall() {
  callCount++;
  let response = callCount === 3
    ? _throw(new Error(callCount))
    : of(callCount);
  return response.pipe(delay(Math.random() * 1000));
}

const EventType = {
  Loading: 'Loading',
  Success: 'Success',
  Failure: 'Failure'
};

const trigger = interval(1000).pipe(take(5));

const stream = trigger.pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return fakeApiCall().pipe(
      map((x) => ({ type: EventType.Success, payload: x })),
      catchError((e) => of({ type: EventType.Failure, payload: e.message })),
      startWith({ type: EventType.Loading })
    );
  }),
  share()
);

const isLoading = stream.pipe(
  map((x) => x.type === EventType.Loading)
);

stream.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log('stream', x); }
);

isLoading.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log('isLoading', x); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.1.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Or you could merge the trigger with the result and map each to the loading status. You have to mute and return something for the error though.

```js
console.clear();
const { interval, merge, of, throwError: _throw } = rxjs;
const { delay, take, switchMap, share, catchError, mapTo, distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs.operators;

let callCount = 0;
function fakeApiCall() {
  callCount++;
  let response = callCount === 2
    ? _throw(new Error(callCount))
    : of(callCount);
  return response.pipe(delay(Math.random() * 1000));
}

const trigger = interval(1000).pipe(take(5));

const stream = trigger.pipe(
  switchMap(() => fakeApiCall().pipe(catchError((e) => of('err')))),
  share()
);

const isLoading = merge(
  trigger.pipe(mapTo(true)),
  stream.pipe(mapTo(false))
).pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged()
);

isLoading.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log('isLoading', x); }
);

stream.subscribe(
  (x) => { console.log('stream next', x); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.1.0/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```